# OpenCL enqueueReadBuffer returns error code -38 CL_INVALID_MEM_OBJECT (macOS)

Tags: c++, macos, opencl, macos-catalina

I am writing a simple OpenCL program in C++. This program sets the array passed into the kernel to "Hello". This program works fine on my Windows 10 machine with NVIDIA Quadro P620 but does not work on my Macbook Pro with Intel Iris Graphics 6100 running on macOS Catalina. On macOS the program runs fine without any errors until I call enqueueReadBuffer which returns error code -38 CL_INVALID_MEM_OBJECT. On both machines it runs on OpenCL 1.2. Do you have any experience or suggestions on how to make it run correctly on macOS ?

```
void Hello() {
   std::vector<cl::Platform> platforms;
   cl::Platform::get(&platforms);

   auto platform = platforms.front();
   std::vector<cl::Device> devices;
   platform.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, &devices);

   auto device = devices.front();
   auto vendor = device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_VENDOR>();
   auto name = device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>();
   auto version = device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_VERSION>();

   std::string source = R"(__kernel void Hello(__global char* A) {
A[0] = 'H';
A[1] = 'E';
A[2] = 'L';
A[3] = 'L';
A[4] = 'O';
A[5] = '\0';
})";

   cl::Program::Sources sources({ std::make_pair(source.c_str(), source.size() + 1) });
   cl::Context context(device);
   cl::Program program(context, sources);

   auto error = program.build(devices);

   // array process
   char data[6];

   cl::Buffer buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(data), &error);
   cl::CommandQueue queue(context, device);
   cl::Kernel kernel(program, "Hello", &error);
   error = kernel.setArg(0, buffer);
   error = queue.enqueueTask(kernel);
   error = queue.enqueueReadBuffer(buffer, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(data), data);
   std::cout << data << "\n";
}
```